# Issue with Creating Directory and Files in Python

Tags: python, list, image, file, directory

I am having issues with running this program.  I am currently using PYCharm in Virtualbox.  Bacically in converted faces from a newspaper clipping into separate images.  I am having trouble overwriting those images every time I run the program, then saving them to a list.  I would like to append the images in the list to a contact sheet.  The first error I receive is files already found.  So I have been deleting the files manually every time I run the program.  The next error is a runtime or logic error.  It prints out the the length of the list as 0 and and empty list.  Thank You in advance

--Did not follow a previous line of code.  Will make changes and comments in the code.  Appending is resolved.  How do I overwrite the existing files every time I run the program.  The two errors are **shutil.move(f,dest) and raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/Images/new_pictures\face_181181_faces.png' already exists**  Thanks Again in advance

```
import zipfile
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
import pytesseract
import shutil

file_name = []
actual_image = []
text_file = []
picture_list = []
grey_image = []
text_from_greyImage = []
thumb_image = []
print(os.getcwd())

face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
#face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

for entry in os.scandir('pyproject'):
    file_name.append(entry.name)

path = os.listdir("pyproject")

i = 0
for file in path:
    img = Image.open(os.path.join('pyproject', file))
    actual_image.append(img)
    img = img.convert('L')
    img.save('grey-'+str(i)+'.png')
    grey_image.append(img)
print('grey Copying is done')

pil_img = Image.open("pyproject/a-0.png")
pil_img = cv.imread("pyproject/a-0.png")
gray = cv.cvtColor(pil_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(30, 30))

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv.rectangle(pil_img,(x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    roi_color = pil_img[y:y + h, x:x +w]
    cv.imwrite('face_'+str(w) + str(h) + 'faces.png', roi_color)
files = os.listdir("/home/pa/PycharmProjects/Proj/")
dest = ("/home/pa/PycharmProjects/Proj/new_pictures")
dest2 = os.listdir('/home/pa/PycharmProjects/Proj/new_pictures')
```

####This is giving me trouble.
   ####This line of code changed and corrected.  img added to append and for statement changed.  Needed to join path, file, directory.

```
for f in files:
    if f.startswith('face'):
        shutil.move(f, dest)
        img = Image.open(os.path.join('new_pictures', f))
        thumb_image.append(img)

"""for f in files:
    if f.startswith('face'):
        shutil.move(f, dest)
   for f in dest2:
    if f.startswith('face'):
        img = Image.open(f)
        thumb_image.append(f)"""


print(len(thumb_image)) ##Outputs correct number
print(thumb_image)  ##Outputs a populated list thankyou.
```

Comment: shouldn`t you be appending img instead of f :    thumb_image.append(img)

Comment: What is the output of `dest2`? and can you try putting a print statement inside the loop for dest2 and see if it actually loops through the files.

Comment: @stefan_business img added.  Thank you.   I combined the for statements and added a line of code that I previously used.  The issue is that I imported this from a Jupyter file and the coding needed to change.  Thank You

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 the output should be new face files or thumbnails of faces.  Your question made me change everything to a relative path and I have on issues ever since.  Thank You.

Comment: The only issues that exists on  this program is how to go about either overwriting the files or deleting the files when the program completes.  For the time being I have been manually deleting files but I think I just answered my own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is difficult to understand and we cannot test it because we don't have the files. We don't know where you are running this program because, the result will be diffrent in one folder or another one. We cannot see what you were trying to do. I have tried to make sense of it:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv
import shutil
import glob

print(os.getcwd())

source_image_filenames = glob.iglob("pyproject/*")
actual_images = (Image.open(current_name) for current_name in source_image_filenames)
grey_images = (img.convert('L') for img in actual_images)

for (current_image_nb, current_image) in enumerate(grey_images):
    current_image.save(f"grey-{current_image_nb}.png")

pil_img = cv.imread("pyproject/a-0.png")
gray = cv.cvtColor(pil_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(30, 30))

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    roi_color = pil_img[y : (y + h), x : (x + w)]
    cv.imwrite(f'face_{w}{h}faces.png', roi_color)

source_filenames = glob.glob("/home/pa/PycharmProjects/Proj/face*")
simple_source_filenames = [os.path.basename(current_file) for current_file in source_filenames]
move_destination = "/home/pa/PycharmProjects/Proj/new_pictures"
move_destination_files = (
    os.path.join(move_destination, current_file))
    for current_file in simple_source_filenames
    )

for (current_source_file, current_destination_file) in zip(source_filenames, move_destination_files):
    shutil.move(current_source_file, current_destination_file)

thumbnail_filenames = (os.path.join('new_pictures', current_thumbnail) 
                       for current_thumbnail in simple_source_filenames)
thumb_image = [Image.open(filename) for filename in thumbnail_filenames]

print(len(thumb_image)) ##Outputs correct number
print(thumb_image)  ##Outputs a populated list thankyou.
```

Does that resemble what you wwre trying to do?